# Dynamically Resizing only one dimension of an element

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui

So I am implementing a UI in SwiftUI and having trouble implementing the little "title tab" all the way to the left in the picture below. Basically I have a title that is rotated 90 degrees to display on the side of the tab and I want the user to be able to enter a custom title so I need the title area to be able to dynamically resize. However I also have it embeded in an HStack and only want it taking a small amount of the space, rather than a full third. When I implement layoutPriority it decreases the horizontal space that the title area takes, but it no longer expands vertically if the title text takes up more space than the other elements in the HStack. If I remove the layoutPriority it expands vertically to display the full title text as I want but also takes up a full third of the HStack which I dont want. Is there a way I am missing to implement this?

[UIElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m4zm.png)

```
                HStack{
                    EventTitleBackground(name:name).rotationEffect(.degrees(270))
                         .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                         .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                         .layoutPriority(2)


                    Spacer()

                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                         Text(time)
                             .font(.title)
                         Spacer()
                         Text("\(truncatedLatitude)  \(truncatedLongitude)")
                             .font(.title)
                         Spacer()

                         Text("Altitude: \(truncatedAltitude)")
                             .font(.title)

                      }
                      .layoutPriority(4)

                      Spacer()

                     VStack(alignment: .leading){
                          HStack{
                              Text("BOBR: \(bobrLargeText)")
                                  .font(.title)
                              Text(" \(bobrSmallText)")
                                  .font(.body)
                      }
                          Spacer()
                          Text("Heading | Course: \(heading) | \(heading)")
                              .font(.title)
                          Spacer()
                          Text("Groundspeed: \(groundSpeed)")
                              .font(.title)

                     }
                      .layoutPriority(4)
                      Spacer()
                }
```

Comment: .layoutPriority is not usable here, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check this simple example. By tap on rectangle you can rotate it and with sliders you can change the "width" of rectangles. To be honest, it works exactly as mentioned in Apple docs.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var angle0 = Angle(degrees: 0)
    @State var angle1 = Angle(degrees: 0)

    @State var width0: CGFloat = 100
    @State var width1: CGFloat = 100

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Color.red.frame(width: width0, height: 50)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.angle0 += .degrees(90)
                }
                .rotationEffect(angle0).border(Color.blue)

                Color.green.frame(width: width1, height: 50)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.angle1 += .degrees(90)
                }
                .rotationEffect(angle1).border(Color.blue)

                Spacer()
            }
            Slider(value: $width0, in: 50 ... 200) {
                Text("red")
            }
            Slider(value: $width1, in: 50 ... 200) {
                Text("green")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

the result is probably far away from what did you expect ...

[image]

Let change the red color part

```
Color.red//.frame(width: width0, height: 50)
    .onTapGesture {
        self.angle0 += .degrees(90)
}
.rotationEffect(angle0).border(Color.blue).frame(width: 50, height: width0)
```

and see the difference

[image]

**Solution for you could be something like**

```
import SwiftUI

struct VerticalText: View {
    let text: String
    @Binding var size: CGSize
    var body: some View {
        Color.red.overlay(
            Text(text).padding().fixedSize()
            .background(
                GeometryReader { proxy -> Color in
                    // avoid layout cycling!!!
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.size = proxy.size
                    }
                    return Color.clear
                }
        ).rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
        )
            .frame(width: size.height, height: size.width)
            .border(Color.green)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var size: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VerticalText(text: "Hello, World!", size: $size)
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus semper eros non condimentum mattis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Mauris aliquam, enim eu vehicula sodales, odio enim faucibus eros, scelerisque interdum libero mi id elit. Donec auctor ipsum at dolor pellentesque, sed dapibus felis dignissim. Sed ac euismod purus, sed sollicitudin leo. Maecenas ipsum felis, ultrices a urna nec, dapibus viverra libero. Pellentesque quis est nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vestibulum luctus a est eget posuere.")
        }.frame(height: size.width)
            .border(Color.red).padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

**See, that the size of VerticalText is stored in the parent, doesn't matter if you use it or not.** Otherwise the parent will not layout properly.